# Command for vector dot with some power

Tags: math-mode, symbols, accents

So what I am trying to type is the square of the derivative of vector x. I tried `\dot{vec{x}}^{\,2}` as well as `\dot{\vec{x}^2}`, but the outputs came out to be very offset. Is there a correct way to do this?

The code I used is:

```
\begin{equation}    
L=\frac{1}{2} m \dot{\vec{x^2}}     
\end{equation}
```

which give me

[image]

Comment: One reason more for not using the arrow for vectors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd probably do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}    
L=\frac{1}{2} m \Dot{\vec{x}}^2     
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

because the Lagrange function is a function of the square of the time derivative of x (and not the time derivative of the square of x).

Comment: That's what I wanted to write, but did not know how to. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a difference between \dot and \Dot?

Comment: @KaneBilliot Short answer: `\Dot` works also when you already have something on top of the symbol. So it would not shift.

Comment: @marmot - For the case at hand, using `\dot` and `\Dot` produce the same result.

Comment: @Mico Yes, you are right.

Comment: At the beginning, `amsmath` provided capitalized versions of the math accent commands, which had to be used for “nested accents”. A later version of `amsmath` made the standard commands (all lowercase) “nesting aware”. The other commands remained for back compatibility.

Comment: I wouldn't forget `^{\,2}`

Answer (score 5):

The first or third option below may be close to what you're looking for. Or, switch from Newton-style to Leibniz-style notation for the derivative, as shown by the fourth option (newly fixed to incorporated @marmot's comment). A separate comment: to make the `\frac{1}{2}` term less visually dominant, consider using `\tfrac` instead of `\frac`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \tfrac macro and general accent-placement support
\begin{document}
\[
\tfrac{1}{2}m \dot{\vec{x}} ^2     \quad
\tfrac{1}{2}m{\dot{\vec{x}}}^2     \quad
\tfrac{1}{2}m{\dot{\vec{x}}}^{\,2} \quad
\tfrac{1}{2}m\bigl(\tfrac{\mathrm{d}\vec{x}}{\mathrm{d}t}\bigr)^{\!2}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure Leibniz didn't use upright d's. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg - I'm pretty sure of that too... I switched to slanted to upright d's mainly on the (now deleted) suggestion of marmot. :-)

Comment: @egreg That's a very bold statement. Did you know Leibniz personally? I would bet a lot of money on having him typeset the d's upright. Assume you have diameter `$d$` that depends on time. How would you typeset its time derivative? `\frac{dd}{dt}`? Not really, right? And after all this is a question on the typesetting a physics Lagrange function, and at least in physics people won't hurt others' eyes by typesetting `\frac{dd}{dt}`.

Comment: @marmot - Wouldn't it be nice to have access to a few first-edition originals -- facsimiles will do too, I suppose -- of Leibniz's own publications? (In case you're curious: I'm afraid I have no such access...)

Comment: @Mico I guess we will not be able to figure out how Leibniz would have typeset it. However, I have a reason for pushing for upright d's, namely examples of the type `\frac{dd}{dt}`. Do you have examples in which upright d's lead to an unfortunate output?

Comment: @marmot - Not off the top of my head. I would suspect, though, that Leibniz (or just about anyone else who's not a complete idiot...) would choose never to make the letter "d" do double-duty as both a variable name and as the differential operator -- upright or slanted. If it's simply imperative to use the letter `d` as a variable name, I'd try to evade the compromising situation by using `D`, `\mathcal{D}`, `\mathfrak{D}`, or what have you. :-) And if somebody really forced me to use `d` as a variable name, I'd probably switch to Newtonian calculus notation...